# OneToMany with composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classed User and Bottom , User has many relationship with Bottom.
User have 2 composite key

userId

```
class TireId {
 private String uId;
 private String schoolId
}
```

User entity :

```
@IdClass(UserId.class)
@Entity
Class User {

 @Id
 private String uId;
 @Id
 private String schoolId

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Bottom> bottoms;


}
```

BottomId :

```
class BottomId {
   private String bId;
   private String cId;
   private String schoolId;

}
```

Bottom class :

```
@IdClass(BottomId.class) 
@Entity
class Bottom {
    private String bId;
   private String cId;
   private String schoolId;
    @ManyToOne
   private  User user;
}
```

In above case hibernate will create 2 additional column in Bottom table name user_uId and user_schoolId .

But I need User oneToMany relation with following relation

```
schoolId of user == schoolId of Bottom
and uId of user == cId of of Bottom
```

how can i archive this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "derived identity", so `BottomId` should look like this:

```
class BottomId {
    private String bId;
    private UserId user; // matches name of attribute and type of User PK
}
```

and `Bottom` should be mapped like this:

```
@IdClass(BottomId.class) 
@Entity
class Bottom {
    @Id
    private String bId;

    @Id
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="cId", referencedColumnName="uId"),
        @JoinColumn(name="schoolId", referencedColumnName="schoolId")
    })
    @ManyToOne
    private  User user;
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.